# How to de[serialize] only selected private fields of a type from and to JSON using Json.NET?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I have a type and I need to round-trip only selected private fields of that type to and from JSON, ignoring all other fields and properties whether public or private.  How can I do that using Json.NET?

My current approach is to use an intermediate `Dictionary<string, object>`.  Serialization works, but deserialization does not

- For serialization, I added a method to my type that constructs a `Dictionary<string, object>` and populates it with the required fields by name.  Later, I serialize the dictionary.

  This works.
- For deserialization, I deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, object>` and then attempt to populate the fields of my type by name and value using reflection.

  **This does not work because the `object` value in the dictionary has the wrong type.**

How can I fix this?

Sample class:

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    // Parameters is a instance of class which is created for storing some values.
    private Dictionary<string, Parameters> SomeParameters;
    private NotificationList notifications ;
    private string someKey;
    private int someNumber;
    private char aChar;

    public MyClass() { }
    public MyClass(Dictionary<string, Parameters> someParameters, NotificationList notifications, string someKey, int someNumber, char aChar) =>
        (this.SomeParameters, this.notifications, this.someKey, this.someNumber, this.aChar) = (someParameters, notifications, someKey, someNumber, aChar);

    //...
    //other properties and fields which should not be [de]serialized for this specific operation.
    public string IgnoreMe { get; set; } = "ignore me";
    private string alsoIgnoreMe = "ignore me";
}

public record Parameters(string Key, string Value);
public class NotificationList : List<string> { }
```

Sample class methods used to create my dictionary, and recreate `MyClass` from a dictionary:

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> ToDictionary() => new()
    {
        { nameof(SomeParameters), SomeParameters},
        { nameof(notifications), notifications },
        { nameof(someKey), someKey },
        { nameof(someNumber), someNumber },
        { nameof(aChar), aChar },
    };
    
    public static MyClass FromDictionary(Dictionary<string, object> settings)
    {
        var instance = new MyClass();

        foreach (string settingValue in settings.Keys)
        {
            Type type = typeof(Dictionary<string, object>);
            FieldInfo? fieldInfo = type.GetField(settingValue, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            // This does not work -- fieldInfo is null, and settings[settingValue] is not the correct type.
            fieldInfo?.SetValue(instance, settings[settingValue]);
        }           
        
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Sample JSON:

```json
{
  "SomeParameters": {
    "name": {
      "Key": "hello",
      "Value": "There"
    }
  },
  "notifications": [],
  "someKey": "some key",
  "someNumber": 101,
  "aChar": "z"
}
```

So key(string) is my field name and object is the field value itself. There is no problem with serializing but I cannot deserialize back the `object`(value) to original type. I searched a lot and could not find any simple solution.

NOTE: I cannot put these variables inside a class and deserialize back. Especially i need to do this operation inside that class and set the values back. It must be done for every field separately.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d7HDGP).

Comment: I don't see a `Dictionary<string, object>` anywhere in your `MyClass`.  Can you explain a little further what you are doing?  Is your `Dictionary<string, object>`  some sort of surrogate to access your internal fields?  If so, can you share a full [mcve]?

Comment: i've updated the question and added some examples.

Comment: @livan3li You have to post a json string. This is an example.

Comment: So basically you're looking to round-trip selected fields of `MyClass` to and from JSON without losing information about the type of each field in the process.  Is that correct?  If so, do you even care whether you use an intermediate `Dictionary<string, object>`, or is that just how you happened to implement your round-trip operation?

Comment: Yes exactly that's what i want. I dont want to lose type of my object variable to be able to deserialize it back. 
So i dont care how de/serialization and stroring data in json is done except it should be done for each field seperately in the class. It cannot be done out side of class.

Comment: So in other words, you have a JSON string, and you want to create some static method on `MyClass` that creates an instance of `MyClass` and populates selected fields from the JSON?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all thanks to [dbc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc) for providing great help. I've updated my need from his answer.

Firstly, i shortly asked as "how can i deserialize and set back to instance of the MyClass" but setting back to instance didnt work. So i changed the way little bit. Now i dont deserialize to instance but i deserialize bak to class instance itself by `this`.

This is the class which i need to [de]serialize. SaveSettings sends the parameters to it's overload method. Overload method takes parameters and add the field names, field type(field type is converted it's string representation) and finaly field's value into `settings` Dictionary which holds all field variables.

Only thing is to do after adding all fields/properties which is asked for is to serialize and save to disk.

When it comes to deserialization, name of  field, it's type and field value(content) is set back inside the class like this:

> fieldInfo?.SetValue(this, ConvertToType(settings[settingValue].Value, typeOfObject))

I've taken `ConvertToType` method from dbc

And I'm determining type of field by

> Type typeOfObject = Type.GetType(settings[settingValue].Key);

This can retrieve the type back which is stored in disk as string. (Breafly, string to type, type to string)

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        private Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, object>> settings = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
        
        private NotificationList notifications ;
                
        private string key;
                
        private string someStrVal;

        private int someNumber = 0;

        public void SaveSettings()
        {
            SaveSettings(new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, object>>()
            {
                { nameof(parameters), new KeyValuePair<string, object>(
                   typeof(Dictionary<string, Parameters>).ToString() ,parameters) },

                { nameof(notifications), new KeyValuePair<string, object>(
                    typeof(NotificationList).ToString(), notifications) },

                { nameof(key), new KeyValuePair<string, object>(
                    typeof(string).ToString(), key) },

                { nameof(someStrVal), new KeyValuePair<string, object>(
                    typeof(string).ToString(), someStrVal) },

                { nameof(someNumber), new KeyValuePair<string, object>(
                    typeof(int).ToString(), someNumber) }

            });
        }

        public void SaveSettings(Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, object>> args)
        {
            if (_IsSettingsVerified == SheetVerification.Verified)
            {
                foreach (string name in args.Keys)
                    settings.Add(name, args[name]);

                string ayarlar = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settings, Formatting.Indented);
                File.WriteAllText(SettingsFileName, ayarlar);
            }
        }
        
        public void LoadTheSettings()
        {
            // SettingsFileName is the json text file path where it is stored
            string settings_text = File.ReadAllText(SettingsFileName);
            settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, object>>>(settings_text);
            
            foreach (string settingValue in settings.Keys)
                if (settings[settingValue].Value != null)
                    {
                        Type type = typeof(MyClass);
                        Type typeOfObject = Type.GetType(settings[settingValue].Key);

                        FieldInfo? fieldInfo = type.GetField(settingValue, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                        fieldInfo?.SetValue(this, ConvertToType(settings[settingValue].Value, typeOfObject));
                    }
        }
        
        object? ConvertToType(object value, Type valueType)
        {
            if (value != null && value.GetType() == valueType)
                return value;
            if (!(value is JToken token))
                token = JToken.FromObject(value!);
            return token.ToObject(valueType);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your `FromDictionary()` method needs two fixes:**

- When you do `type.GetField(settingValue, ...)` the type you use must be `typeof(MyClass)` not `typeof(Dictionary<string, object>)`.
- Before setting the field value, you must deserialize or convert the dictionary value to the type of the field.

This can be done as follows:

```
public static MyClass FromDictionary(Dictionary<string, object> settings)
{
    var instance = new MyClass();
    var type = typeof(MyClass);
    
    foreach (var pair in settings)
    {
        var fieldInfo = type.GetField(pair.Key, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        // This does not work -- fieldInfo is null, and settings[settingValue] is not the correct type.
        if (fieldInfo == null)
            continue; // or throw an exception;
        fieldInfo.SetValue(instance, JsonExtensions.ConvertToType(pair.Value, fieldInfo.FieldType));
    }           
    
    return instance;
}
```

Using the following extension method:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static object? ConvertToType(object value, Type valueType)
    {
        if (value != null && value.GetType() == valueType)
            return value;
        if (!(value is JToken token))
            token = JToken.FromObject(value!);
        return token.ToObject(valueType);
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/POPxGw).

**As an alternative**, if you need to serialize and deserialize only specific (possibly private) fields of some type, you can do this directly with a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples).  Using one completely eliminates the need for some intermediate `Dictionary<string, object>` and so avoids the need to somehow guess the type of the value objects when deserializing.

First define the following resolver:

```
public class SelectedFieldsContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    readonly Dictionary<Type, string []> typesAndFields;
    
    public SelectedFieldsContractResolver(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Type, string []>> typesAndFields) =>
        (this.typesAndFields) = typesAndFields.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);

    protected override List<MemberInfo> GetSerializableMembers(Type objectType) => 
        objectType switch
        {
            var t when typesAndFields.TryGetValue(t, out var fields) => fields.Select(f => (MemberInfo)objectType.GetField(f, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)!).Where(f => f != null).ToList(),
            _ => base.GetSerializableMembers(objectType),
        };
        
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (member is FieldInfo f && f.ReflectedType != null && typesAndFields.ContainsKey(f.ReflectedType))
            property.Readable = property.Writable = true;
        return property;
    }
}
```

Then, modify `MyClass` as follows:

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    static Lazy<JsonSerializerSettings> settings = 
        new(() =>
            new JsonSerializerSettings ()
            {
                ContractResolver = 
                    new SelectedFieldsContractResolver(
                        new KeyValuePair<Type, string []> [] 
                        {
                            new(typeof(MyClass), 
                                new [] { nameof(SomeParameters), nameof(notifications), nameof(someKey), nameof(someNumber), nameof(aChar) })
                        }),
            });
    
    public static MyClass FromSelectedFieldsJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json, settings.Value);
    
    public string ToSelectedFieldsJson(Formatting formatting = Formatting.None) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, formatting, settings.Value);
```

And now you will be able to round-trip your selected fields to and from JSON as follows:

```
var json = myClass.ToSelectedFieldsJson(Formatting.Indented);

var myClass2 = MyClass.FromSelectedFieldsJson(json);
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kpLBB7).

Comment: Thank you very much. I've solved the problem by your help and posted entire solution as new answer. But static instance of the MyClass didnt work i had to change code little bit.

Answer (score 0):

your code is very slopy. Just use this FromDictionary code

```
public static MyClass FromDictionary(Dictionary<string, object> settings)
{
    return  JObject.FromObject(settings).ToObject<MyClass>();
}
```

and mark your constructor with parameters  as [JsonConstructor]

```
[JsonConstructor]
public MyClass(Dictionary<string, Parameters> someParameters, NotificationList notifications, string someKey, int someNumber, char aChar)
```

and IMHO

```
public class NotificationList : List<string> { }
```

I have never seen any good from collection inheritance

Comment: I'm new to .Net and C# :) and NotificationList : List<string> has a purpose not like you think.

Comment: @livan3li It is never good, doesn't matter what is a purpouse.

Comment: That list is needed to be inherited so that some of the elements of the list needs to be removed and some other operations need to be done as well as soon as initialization is finished when deserialization is done? If it's not good then what would you suggest?

Comment: If  for some reason you want to put all code together,  I would suggest to create a class with a List property inside of the class.

Comment: ok i'm gonnad try to change it. Thank you very much for your help